# TextBlock.Foreground defined in a style is ignored

Tags: .net, wpf

I have defined a named Style for TextBlock setting font size and foreground color and several textblock instances using this style within user controls.
While the `FontSize` setting of the style is always applied, the `Foreground` setting is only applied if the `FontWeight` property of the text block is explicitly set.

Here's the XAML:

Note that Style and TextBlock are actually not in the same file, but in the same assembly. The text block is rendered in size 22 but with black foreground.

```
<Style x:Key="StandardTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF999999"/>
</Style>

<TextBlock Text="Test." 
           Style="{DynamicResource StandardTextBlockStyle}"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="0,5,3,0" 
           Grid.Column="0" 
           Grid.Row="0" />
```

If I set the `FontWeight` property of the text block explicitly (no matter to which value), the foreground setting of the style is applied:

```
<TextBlock Text="Test." 
           Style="{DynamicResource StandardTextBlockStyle}"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           FontWeight="Regular"
           Margin="0,5,3,0" 
           Grid.Column="0" 
           Grid.Row="0" />
```

The main method of my program basically looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    Application app = new Application();
    Window w = new TestWindow();

    var resource = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/TestProg.UIL;component/SkinBright.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resource);

    app.Run(w);
}
```

`SkinBright.xaml` is the resource dictionary which contains the `StandardTextBlockStyle` mentioned above.

Any ideas why this happens and how to avoid the need to set the font weight on all text blocks?

Comment: how to your import your style to your resources?

Comment: What version of WPF are you using?

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: It's WPF 4.0 (updated title accordingly).

Comment: @blindmeis: I don't, I'm adding the resource dictionary to the application in code. Since the font size of the style is set properly, not finding the style can't be the issue.

Comment: @Mathias: can you perhaps expand your question to show exactly how and where you're adding the resource dictionary?

Comment: @KentBoogaart: Done. I couln't copy & paste the code, though, because it is distributed across some methods.

Answer (score 1):

i tried your code and it works (EDIT .NET4.0)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum"
               Style="{DynamicResource StandardTextBlockStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well, that's no surprise. I haven't managed to construct a small sample showing the false behavior, either. But in my application with a complex UI and lots of user controls--for some unknown reason--it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: did you try to use Snoop to see whats going on?

Comment: no, I have no experience with this tool. Would it show me where the current value of the foreground property of a textblock comes from? Pls keep in mind that the style gets applied partially, only the foreground setter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Style x:Key="StandardTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
```